# GoogleCredential deprecated

Tags: java, google-api, gmail, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

Trying to get Gmail service and it should up the message 'com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential' is deprecated.

Here is my code snippet.

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

    public Gmail getGmailService() throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(SecurityConstant.CREDENTIALS.concat(environment).concat(SecurityConstant.JSON_EXTENSION));
        try {
          if (null != inputStream) {
            GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String clientId = clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId();
            String clientSecret = clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret();
            Credential authorize = new **GoogleCredential**.Builder().setTransport(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport())
                    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                    .setClientSecrets(clientId,
                            clientSecret)
                    .build().setAccessToken(getAccessToken(clientId, clientSecret, refreshToken));
            final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            inputStream.close();
            return new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, authorize)
                    .setApplicationName(SecurityConstant.MODULE_NAME).build();
    
          }
        } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException exception) {
          exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried looking on stack overflow there's a lot of questions relating to this already.

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: @Nexarius I want to replace the deprecated use of GoogleCredential. I tried a few things but it didn't work.